# How to delete specific fields in a mongoDb via mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, gdprconsentform

I'm trying to delete only specific fields in my mongoDb user document but i don't think using the `userModel.deleteOne({_id:id})` would not suffice as this would delete the entire document which isn't what i want.

```
{
    "_id": "12345678" ,
    "dob": null,
    "createdAt":  "2021-09-16T09:11:55.199Z" ,
    "email": "287983@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "iam1234",
    "lastName": "test14",
    "webisite": "hello-world.com",
    "uid": "SKkZZ3a",
    "skills": []
}
```

in this context, I want to delete `firstName, lastName email website skills dob`. Leaving me with just `_id and uid`

Answer (score 0):

```
userModel.update({_id:id},{$unset:{"email":undefined}})
```

in this example we delete `email` field